# ¿Es posible hacer que la exportación de imágenes de highcharts funcione offline?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, highcharts

buscando herramientas para realizar gráficos dinámicos que sean utilizables con php, jvascript, ajax, mysql, ya que son las herramientas que he utilizado, me he topado con highcharts la cual considero una herramienta muy completa, sin embargo el sistema que me encuentro realizando funciona de manera local, ya que es uno de los requisitos del proyecto, por lo que habiendo programado y probado me he dado cuenta que sus herramientas de exportación son completamente online, en esto me refiero por ejemplo a cuando quiero exportar la grafica a imagen o pdf, cuando estoy conectada a internet funciona perfectamente sin embargo cuando estoy sin internet no me permite exportar, por lo que realizo la siguiente pregunta para poder conservar la estructura actual de mi proyecto con highcharts ya que me ha agradado bastante esta herramienta.

¿Es posible configurar la exportacion de highcharts a que funcione sin internet de maneral local?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Qué significa "completamente online"? Qué quieres decir con offline?

Comment: @Comunidad ya he editado la pregunta espero poder haberme explicado

Comment: @Alfabravo actualmente mi proyecto es desarrollado para un lugar donde solo utilizaran un servidor local sin internet por lo que me encuentro usando XAMPP, la conexion a internet en dicho lugar es bastante inestable entonces como requisito del proyecto tengo el hecho de no requerir internet, a eso me refiero con offline

Comment: No sabemos cómo construiste tu aplicación. Así pues, no hay respuesta concisa a tu pregunta en su formato actual. Como comentario, sugeriría que los recursos los tengas localmente y no los descargues (las librerías JS, por ejemplo, que suelen ofrecerse desde una CDN)